# Send out [newsletters]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[newsletters](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newsletters) has no usage guidance, there are 14 questions tagged with it, mainly about format of newsletters, or sending newsletters in e-mail.

I see it from time to time as a favoured tag of spam questions.

Should we clean it up?

Comment: I have no objections to it being removed.

Comment: there are no longer any questions tagged `newsletter`, but the tag still exists.

Comment: @Ploni The tag is gone. I can create a tag [tag:with-any-name] and the system will show me a page as if that tag existed. The tag effectively disappears 24 hours after it is removed from the last question, so [tag:newsletters] is gone.